# Minimal set and $\epsilon$-dense

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, dynamical-systems

Let $f:X\to X$ be a homeomorphism  on compact metric space $(X, d)$ and $K$ be a minimal set, i.e. a compact  $f$-invariant set that for all $x\in K$, the orbit $O(x)$ is dense in $K$.

In a paper, author claim that for every $\epsilon>0$ there is $n\geq 0$ such that for all $x\in X$, the set $O_n(x)=\{f^{i}(x)\}_{i=-n}^n$ is $\epsilon$-dense i.e. for all $y\in K$ there is $j\in \{-n, -n+1, \ldots, n\}$  such that $d(y, f^j(x))<\epsilon$.

Proof of it, is not clear for me. Please help me to know it.

Answer (score 3):

Since $\{f^i(x)\}_{i= -\infty}^{\infty}$ is dense, the set of all balls $B_{\epsilon}(f^i(x))$ centred at $f^i(x)$ and of radius $\epsilon$ is an open covering of $K$. Since $K$ is compact, there must exist a finite subcovering. Therefore, we can choose $i_1 \ldots i_l$ such that $\{f^{i_k}(x)\}_{k=1}^{l}$ is $\epsilon$-dense. Now $i_1 \ldots i_l$ must be a subset of $[-n,n] \cap \mathbb{Z}$ for some $n$.

Comment: Thanks.  In my question, $x\notin K$, hence we can not say $\{f^i(x)\}$ is dense in $K$.

Comment: In that case the theorem is not true. You might take $X = \mathbb{C}$, $K = \{|z|=1\}$, and $f(z) = e^i \cdot z$ as a counterexample.

Comment: In my question, $X$ is a compact metric space.

Comment: Ok, take $X$ to be the set $\{z \in \mathbb{C}| |z| \leq 10\}$. Still disproves the theorem

Comment: Thanks for your example. What do you mean by $f(z)=e^i.z$. Would you please give me some more details on your example.

Comment: Just taking any complex number and turning it one radian in the positive direction